# Python ThreadPoolExecutor not running parallelly

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading

Python ThreadPoolExecutor not running parallelly, it is calling cube method in sequence and waiting for complete,

where I need to run 20 parallell threads

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep

def cube(x):
    sleep(2)
    print(f'Cube of {x}:{x*x*x}')

count = 0
while True:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as exe:
        exe.submit(cube,2)
    count += 1
    if count > 50:
        break
```

Comment: This is because `cube` function is CPU bound function. I think you have to use multiprocessing instead of multithreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"with" statement uses __enter__ method for ThreadPoolExecutor, it initialize thread pool at this moment. So, for function execution in thread pool we should use it inside "with" statement.

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as exe:  # for default it will be number of os.cpu_count()
    futures = []
    for i in range(50):
        futures.append(executor.submit(cube, i))
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        print(future.result())
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess want something like this:

```
from concurrent import futures
from time import sleep

THREADS = 20

def cube(x):
    sleep(2)
    res = x*x*x
    print(f'Cube of {x}:{res}')
    return res

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=THREADS) as exe:
    jobs = {exe.submit(cube, i): i for i in range(THREADS)}

    for job in futures.as_completed(jobs):
        try:
            data = job.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (jobs[job], exc))
        else:
            print(f"Result of thread {jobs[job]}: {data})")
```

Out:

```
Cube of 2:8
Cube of 1:1
Cube of 3:27
Cube of 0:0
Cube of 4:64
Result of thread 2: 8)
Result of thread 1: 1)
Result of thread 0: 0)
Result of thread 4: 64)
Cube of 5:125
Cube of 6:216
Cube of 8:512
Cube of 14:2744
Cube of 12:1728
Cube of 17:4913
Result of thread 3: 27)
Cube of 13:2197
Cube of 7:343
Cube of 16:4096
Cube of 15:3375
Cube of 18:5832
Cube of 11:1331
Cube of 9:729
Cube of 19:6859
Cube of 10:1000
Result of thread 5: 125)
Result of thread 6: 216)
Result of thread 8: 512)
Result of thread 14: 2744)
Result of thread 12: 1728)
Result of thread 17: 4913)
Result of thread 13: 2197)
Result of thread 7: 343)
Result of thread 16: 4096)
Result of thread 15: 3375)
Result of thread 18: 5832)
Result of thread 11: 1331)
Result of thread 10: 1000)
Result of thread 19: 6859)
Result of thread 9: 729)
```

Comment: I am submitting jobs as I received from yield output (one output) from other method, if I am checking jobs.completed, its not going to run, any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be something you want to achieve:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep

def cube(x):
    print(f'Starting {x}')
    sleep(2)
    print(f'Cube of {x}:{x*x*x}')

count = []
for i in range (0,50):
    count.append(i)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as exe:
    exe.map(cube,count)
```